# Can I use NPM to run Ubuntu apt-get and Search Packages

Tags: node.js, npm, apt, dpkg

I have got NodeJS and NPM in my machine. Now my question is can I use NPM to search for a specific application in the repository or to list all the applications in a single category?

Elaborating the question further, I would like to do the following things:

**1. Search a single application:**

Something like `search firefox` and then get the return results as promise or anything otherwise.

**2. List all applications in a category:**

Something like `list internet` should list all apps with the "internet" category like browsers, email clients, download managers, etc.

**3. Install and remove apps:**

Firing the command `sudo apt install <app-name>`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt remove <app-name>`

I have found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-apt-get on the internet and this seems to do a little bit of work but I am unable to find much help on the internet. It would be nice if you suggest some recommendations for this task.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know this is possible because there are NPM packages even capable of changing the display's brightness and do all the talking even with the hardware and it won't be hard for NPM to fetch a software generated list. I just don't know where to look for it.

Comment: if you can write *the* `shell scripts`, by all means yes

Comment: @1556089774 Any resources if you can recommend

Comment: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/

Comment: You can't use NPM to search Packages for Ubuntu. NPM mean Node Package Manager. For Ubuntu we have apt-get. If you want to list all the packages that you have installed, you can use "list" command.

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee Please read the question properly. It says I need a way to communicate between apt-get and npm. I do know Ubuntu commands and what npm means. Please don't post irrelevant content.